# Need "document.write" to only write inside a specific element, not overwrite the whole page

Tags: javascript

I need to use a widget in my page. The widget simply use document.write to insert a link and image to my page. In my js file I have:

```
var adScript1 = document.getElementById("adscript1");
adScript1.addEventListener("load", function () {
OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN');
});
adScript.src =    "https://oasc12.247realmedia.com/RealMedia/ads/adstream_mjx.ads";
```

as you can see this link loads a function which contains document.write... and after I call OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN'); it will be executed.

Also my html is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="non-mobile-ad">

    <div class="sidebox advertisement">
        <script id="adscript1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/ads2.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is that when the OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN') is executed all of the divs such as  are removed from the page and I just see a link and image. This means that document.write overwrite the whole page. How can I have execute the OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN'); without overwriting the whole page since I want OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN'); to write a link and img inside the existing div. Just for more explanation I can not change the widget since I have no control over that.

Comment: That's what `document.write()` does. You need to use DOM manipulation APIs instead.

Comment: but if I can somehow load the widget before laod happens this will be fixed am I right? (Since I have no control of the widget and I cannot change the document.write)

Comment: You could load the widget into an `<iframe>`.

Comment: @Pointy Yes but the widget returns a function and I need to call that when function load on my side.

Comment: @Pointy  is there anyway that I can execute the loaded function in iframe? because now when I try ifram as you suggested the whole function is loaded in the iframe